# Why ide shows "[Error] incompatible type for argument"?

Tags: c

I'm beginner in C and I don't understand why when i run the code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DIMMAX 5
#define MAXSTRINGA 20

typedef struct{
    
    int num;
    int den;
    
} Razionale;


typedef Razionale Matrice[DIMMAX][DIMMAX];

void aquisisciRazionale(Razionale);
void acquisisciMatrice(Matrice[DIMMAX][DIMMAX]);

void aquisisciRazionale(Razionale n){
    
    printf("Inserire numeratore: ");
    scanf("%d", &n.num);
    printf("Inserire denominatore: ");
    scanf("%d", &n.den);
    
}

void acquisisciMatrice(Matrice mat[DIMMAX][DIMMAX]){
    

    int i, j;
    
    for(i=0; i<DIMMAX; i++){
        
        for(j=0; j<DIMMAX; j++){
            
            aquisisciRazionale(mat[i][j]);
             
             
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    Matrice m[DIMMAX][DIMMAX];
    acquisisciMatrice(m);

}
```

I have this error:

> [Error] incompatible type for argument 1 of 'aquisisciRazionale'
>
> [Note] expected 'Razionale' but argument is of type 'struct Razionale (*)[5]'

I don't understand if there is an error when I define structures or when I define functions. Can someone help me?

Comment: Not related to the question, but you can declare counter variables right inside of `for`, like this: `for(int i = 0; i < DIMMAX; i++)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: incompatible type for argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546076/error-incompatible-type-for-argument)

Comment: Avoid typedefs. they only exist to confuse you.

Comment: For future reference, please do a search for the error message on Google, leaving out your variable names. I searched for "error incompatible type for argument" and got three relevant SO posts at the top of the search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Matrice` typedef is already a 2-dimensional array. When you declare your function

```
void acquisisciMatrice(Matrice mat[DIMMAX][DIMMAX]){
```

you're saying that `mat` is a 2-dimensional array of `Matrice`, which is a 4-dimensional array of `Razionale`. `mat[i][j]` is then a `Matrice`, not a `Razionale`.

The function should just be

```
void acquisisciMatrice(Matrice mat){
```

since the dimensions are part of the `Matrice` typedef. You should also change the variable in `main()`:

```
Matrice m;
acquisisciMatrice(m);
```

Note that `acquisisciRazionale()` will not fill in the matrix elements in `acquisisciMatrice()`. When you call

```
acquisisciRazionale(mat[i][j]);
```

you're passing a copy of the array element. `scanf()` is then writing into that copy, which has no effect on the original array. You should pass a pointer.

```
acquisisciRazionale(&mat[i][j]);
```

and change the function to:

```
void aquisisciRazionale(Razionale *n){

    printf("Inserire numeratore: ");
    scanf("%d", &(n->num));
    printf("Inserire denominatore: ");
    scanf("%d", &(n->den));

}
```